# ~0 vs. !0 vs. 1 in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I was reading some code today by someone I consider to be a reasonable programmer, and I noticed they used `a =~0` to set a loop quit variable.

Is there any compelling reason to do this rather than simply `quit = 1;`?

I'm mostly just curious, before I go ahead and change it. Thanks!

Example:

```
while(!quit){
    ...;

    if(!strcmp(s, "q")) 
        quit=~0;
}
```

Comment: Did they use `~=` or `=~` ? You have both written in your question

Comment: Wow, my bad :) They used =~0. I wrote the other one accidentally. Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: NP, I am almost positive `~=` is not a valid operator.

Comment: @GWW: `~=` isn't valid in C because `~` is a unary operator with no binary equivalent. `~=` is common in Perl, though.

Comment: It matters what type `quit` has. Unless it's an unsigned type, this code is bogus.

Comment: Maybe someone spilled some coffee on the `1` key. So, cannot use `1` anymore, not `!0` too - so `~0` is the next best thing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no strong reason for that, unless some other code tests `quit` differently, such as testing any other bit.  `!0` is one, but `~0` is -1 on all modern architectures.

On some architectures ~0 is faster than !0, though that should be optimized away by any decent compiler.

Comment: `~0` is also not a reliable way to get a nonzero value. It could yield 0, e.g. one a ones complement machine.

Comment: @R:  I used one's complement machines for many years—they are damned annoying.  Inverting 0 sets all bits there too.  You might be thinking of negative zero being negated.  Never ask the question of a one's complement machine:  "what is the difference between zero and negative zero?"

Comment: @ikegami: it makes sense precisely *because* `~` is the one's complement operator. On a one's complement machine, `-x` is represented by the bit pattern `~x`. Hence `~0` is `0` (well, negative zero). That's if you're lucky - if the implementation doesn't support negative zeroes then behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

`~0` is usually -1, while `!0` is defined to be 1.

Of course, `!~0` and `!!0` are both 0, so there is no compelling reason to use one or the other, aside from the fact that `~0` is non-idiomatic (meaning that people won't know what the heck you're doing).

Comment: `!~0` is implementation defined and could be either 0 or 1.

Comment: @R..: `~0` is an integer with all bits set to 1. `!0` is defined to be 1, while `!(anything non-0)` is defined to be 0. The only way `!~0` could be 0 is if `~0 == 0`. I can't imagine an architecture where that would be true.

Comment: @Gabe: your lack of imagination doesn't constrain the C standard. Check 6.2.6.2

Comment: An integer can either be twos complement, ones complement, or sign and magnitude. In the second case, all-one-bits is a second representation for zero.

Comment: @Steve: Should I edit my answer to tell the OP that his code won't be portable to some UNIVACs?

Comment: @Gabe: if the OP is reading any of the comments, he knows that by now. It's the usual issue of whether we program to the standard, or program to some set of implementations with which we're familiar. Since in this case the code has to go out of its way to be non-portable, its a no-brainer: `1` is simpler and portable as a true value, so `~0` is inferior on two counts.

Answer (score 0):

In C, ~ is the unary operator for ones compliment which flips bits to their opposite state. So technically the code works because the if() clause is only evaluating for the presence of 0 (false) or anything not 0 (true). Frankly I think this is a bit overkill for evaluating true or false. I'd only consider using it if I was truly doing evaluations on a bitwise basis. Maybe there could be an argument made for performance but I somehow doubt it.

Comment: This also assumes that ~0 is not zero, which is true on virtually any computer you're likely to encounter today, but not all that C has been used on in the past.